# add generated column with aggregated over a partion and sort

Tags: sql, aggregate, calculated-columns, data-partitioning

I am trying to add a calculated column that computes a rolling average of a sorted partition. I can make it work as a query but cannot seem to get the result to become a calculated field.

```sql
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC "minutes" 
    ADD COLUMN "green_avg" NUMERIC (10,2) 
    AS GENERATED AVG("price") OVER(PARTITION BY "key"
    ORDER BY "endtime" ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

Comment: You can't use a window function as a generated column expression.

Comment: Depending on the make and model of the `RDBMS` you are using, which one is it?, you can perhaps have a calculated column in a `View`